# Measure length of shadow from object center in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, line, geometry, intersection

I am trying to measure the length of object shadows in QGIS 3 in order to calculate the object's height.

In order to know height (h) I will need to have:

- The length (l) of the cathetus (line from center of object to the tip of the shadow).
- Angle (α) of sun at that particular place and at that particular time.

[image]

So considering the sun azimuth angle and height is easy to know, I thought this might be possible in qgis by drawing a line (l) in the direction opposite to the sun in relation to the object, and then intersect this with the shadow edge. The segment would be the length l.

Here is an example cenario:

[image]

Ideally I would like to perform this operation using a script so I can scale to dozens of objects at once from a shadow map and point layer.

So basically how can I generate this line starting at point (x,y) and in direction (degrees)?

Comment: Yes, this will be possible. I'd suggest you build what you need until you get stuck and then ask about the specific problem you got stuck with or you formulate this post as a specific question. Right now it is not clear what your actual question is. ;)

Comment: Did you have a look at GRASS tool `r.sunmask.position`? It "Calculates cast shadow areas from sun position and elevation raster map". It's always a good idea to go to Menu `Processing / Toolbox` and type a few terms connected to what you want to do (here: `sun`) to see if there are any tools available for this or similar tasks.

Comment: @Babel Because the shadows will be extracted from optical data (and not a DSM), I think this step would be unnecessary.

Comment: @Steffan - if working in flat areas, you could imitage a "flat" DEM by just creating a raster with constant values

Comment: Depending on the type of object you are trying to determinate height, using the center of the object may not be best place to start your measurement

Comment: This will give you accurate height only in flat area (a DEM could be used to take relief into account by adding or subtracting the elevation difference between the start and end point of your measurement)